# What is the difference in bases of a trapezoid called?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, euclidean-geometry, terminology

In a trapezoid, is there a term for the difference in length of the two parallel bases? A parallelogram  has difference 0.  I have found this quantity to be very important in many proofs involving trapezoids, enough to warrant a name - yet can find no name.

Comment: I don't belive there is or there neeeds to be one.

Comment: You would definitely need to preface this definition, but my reverse-etymological attempt is *diabasis* from Greek *dia-* meaning *between* or *apart*.

Comment: @Graviton And _diabasis_ has the advantage that **d**ifference in **b**ases resembles **d**ia**b**asis